# Windows 10 login screen background

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

Hello today I just upgraded from 8.1 to windows 10, everything went fine but I'm stuck on a simple thing.

How on earth can I change this really bad blue background on the windows login screen right after the lock screen?

I've tried changing images in C:\Windows\Web\ directories but nothing changed.

That background is driving me nuts...

**UPDATE**

So far the only thing that helps me get ird of the image is this (I'm posting the contents of a .reg file):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink ; http://www.tenforums.com ; Tutorial: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9108-sign-screen-background-image-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System] "DisableLogonBackgroundImage"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: The only way I found so far is to use a separate piece of [software](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/change-the-login-screen-background-in-windows-10/). I couldn't find a method using images/directories or the registry yet but maybe someone will figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

First, click start and then select settings from the settings panel.
[image]

When the settings app opens, select personalisation and then lock screen.  from here, you should be able to select a lock screen wallpaper to use.
[image]

If its the password entry screen you are looking to change, things are somewhat more involved, so take a look at [This app](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/change-the-login-screen-background-in-windows-10/) which can accomplish this for you quickly and easily.. worked for me.

Comment: Have you used this app recently with success? Did you have the desired effect? (I'm talking about the login screen not the lock screen)

Comment: @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas - Have you?  If you want to change the login image, it requires modifying a file, hence the application that was linked to.